# Apply permissions to NTFS USB drive on Auto-mount

Tags: 20.04, usb, permissions, automount, udev

I have a external USB hard drive that I'd like my backup program to write backups to. The backup program requires certain permissions. I understand that NTFS under Ubuntu doesn't allow me to set unix-style permissions on directories or files... I must apply the necessary permissions to the HDD root during mount time. I want this drive to continue to be auto-mounted. I've learned about udev rules, and tried to use those. However I saw serious errors where the drive became inaccessible.

For the udev matchers, this appears to work: `ATTRS{vendor}=="ASMT", ATTRS{model}=="2105"`. But I'm unsure about everything after that. Initially, I was able to get the group name changed on `/dev/sd??`, but (a) I can't reproduce it now and (b) when it did work, it still didn't affect the permissions on the mounted drive... I'm guessing the only way to change those is to change the `mount` command.

What I know:

- I know about using `blkid` to get the current device path of the drive.
- I know about using `udevadm monitor --environment --udev` to get info when plugging in or unplugging the usb drive
- I know about using `udevadm info -a -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sd?)` to get possible matchers for the device
- I know about using `sudo udevadm control --reload` to reload changes I make to the rules files in `/etc/udev/rules.d`
- Putting something like `RUN+="echo bingo %k"` in the rules file will cause it to show up in the `udevadm test` output, which makes me believe my matchers are fine.

What I don't know:

- How to prevent or override the automount based on the udev rules file, so that I can put a `mount` command of my own in the rules file. (I had a mount command in there at one point, but it resulted in errors and the drive became unaccessible).
- How effective the `udevadm control --reload` really is. (I can't seem to duplicate some of the partial successes I had using `GROUP="urbackup", MODE="0666"`.)
- If `udev` rules are the way to go here. All I want to do is modify the mounted drive permissions.
- If the number at the beginning of the udev rule filename really matters for my use case, I've tried low numbers like `10`, and high ones like `100`.

Ubuntu 20.04.

Here are some details:
The latest rule I have is `ATTRS{vendor}=="ASMT", ATTRS{model}=="2105", ACTION=="add", GROUP="urbackup", MODE="0666", RUN+="/usr/bin/mount -o umask=001,dmask=007,fmask=117,gid=134,uid=1000 /dev/%k /media/eddie/Interstellar"`. -- the `udevadm test` shows the run command, but after reloading the rules and actually plugging in the drive, nothing seems to have changed.

Update: if I change the command slightly to:
`ATTRS{vendor}=="ASMT", ATTRS{model}=="2105", ACTION=="add", GROUP="urbackup", MODE="0666", RUN+="/usr/bin/mount -o umask=001,dmask=007,fmask=117,gid=134,uid=1000 /dev/%k /media/Interstellar"` --- and set the file name to start with `10-`, then after power cycling the usb drive I get the `Transport endpoint is not connected` error. I do not get this error when using `70-` at the start of the file name, but then it acts as if I hadn't created a udev rule at all.

Answer (score 0):

Short version:

If changing the group on the auto-mounted external drive is the only custom thing you need, udev rules are not the correct solution. For this, `fstab` edits are the way to go. I found this out by trying the `Disks` UI which gives the option to edit mount options on an HDD partition. After playing around with it, I realized it was just a UI for creating an `fstab` entry. In particular, for this problem I needed to add `gid=<groupId>` to the mount options. I also used `umask`,`dmask`, and `fmask` values, as well as `uid=<userId>`, but I'm unsure which of those were strictly necessary. Here is the full line that the `Disks` UI helped me write to FSTAB:

```
LABEL=Interstellar /media/Interstellar auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,umask=001,dmask=007,fmask=117,gid=134,uid=1000,noauto 0 0
```